# what portable ways exist to switch the stack frame to an arbitrary buffer

Tags: c++, c

What portable ways exist to change the stack frame to an arbitrary buffer? Say to:

```
char stack[1024];
```

or

```
new char[1024];
```

Comment: There are no portable ways to do this.

Comment: I'd recommend a `std::stack` and loops or such.

Comment: It's a common misconception that C standardises anything about the "stack" and the "heap".

Comment: ^^^^ Same for C++.

Comment: `va_start, va_arg` won't work.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Of course C++ does. It standardizes `make_heap`, `push_heap`, `pop_heap` etc. :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17768925/315052

Comment: The least un-portable way is to use `std::longjmp`. But it's not guaranteed to save all state you're interested in. So it would probably have to be supported by some assembly code (that was the case when I used it for some co-routine like stuff in the 1990s), and then for portability  you'd be worse off for having added the dependency on that function. By the way, just ignore the terminology comments. They're not constructive, they essentially just say that those making those comments, lack a reasonably good understanding of things.

Comment: I meant, least un-portable using only the standard library. I'd forgotten about Boost.Context, pointed by Travis Gockel in his answer below. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [Boost.Context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html). To switch the current running context (what you are calling a "stack") to an arbitrary buffer, use [`boost::context::preallocated`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/struct__preallocated_.html) when creating your `boost::context::context<T>` instance.